# UIIView to CGContext coordinate system in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to capture screen shots and make a movie. Everything works fine in portrait mode, but my app is only a landscape app.

I am using this method to add the UIImage.CGImageRef into the video:

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef)pixelBufferFromCGImage:(CGImageRef)image  withSize:(CGSize)frameSize
{
    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer;

    if (pixelBufferPool == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"pixelBufferPool is null!");
        return nil;
    }
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferPoolCreatePixelBuffer (NULL, pixelBufferPool, &pxbuffer);
    if(status != kCVReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"failed to create pixel buffer pool pixel buffer %i", status);
        return nil;
    }
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, frameSize.width,
                                                 frameSize.height, 8, 4*frameSize.width, rgbColorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);

    //CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    //t = CGAffineTransformRotate(t, 0/*M_PI_2*/);
    //t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, -1.0, 1.0);
    //CGContextConcatCTM(context, t);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image), CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);

    return pxbuffer;
}
```

The video is as if the images are skewed. I know its because the coordinate system of UIImage and CGContext is different, hence the frames are skewed. But I don't know how to fix this.

I tried rotating, scaling, etc. But everything needs to be in the correct order.

What is the coordinate system of a UIImage in a landscape app, and the coordinate system of the CGContext?

What is the correct transform that I need?

[image: Screen Shot]

[image: Movie]

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if the app is launching in landscape mode, the frame of the view should already have the correct sizing, therefore you don't need to rotate your context.

You will only have to flip the y-axis of the context, by the following:

```
CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1, -1);
CGContextTranslateCTM(c, 0, -size.height);
```

Comment: hmmm... actually thinking about it, the view should already have the correct sizings, so long as the view size is based off `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`. You just have to flip the context.

Comment: What does flipping "the context" mean? Do I push the new context and then draw?

Comment: Well you'll need to flip the y-axis of the context to matchup with the UIKit coordinate system. Yes, you should push then draw. I think Justin might right about the origin of your sheering problem though...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be happening because the size of the `CGContext` doesn't match the size of the `CVPixelBuffer`? When you draw your image, you're probably walking past the end of the row and start drawing pixels on the following row, because your landscape image is wider than the pixel buffer's width.

What if you created your `CGContext` with a size that's based on the pixel buffer's size, and then if the pixel buffer size doesn't match the `frameSize`, then you apply your rotation transform?

Or, alternatively, when you're in landscape mode, re-create the pixel buffer pool with a different size that matches the landscape size.

(I'm not familiar with the CoreVideo API, so that's just a guess, though)

Comment: I am creating the pixel buffer on the UIViewController's view size. So that is whatever the landscape view size is.

Comment: So you're sure the size of the pixel buffer is the same as the size of the bitmap context? Might be worth double-checking in the debugger to be sure.